# My PWA application has errors in the fetch event handler

Tags: typescript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, sveltekit

I have a PWA developed with SvelteKit.
I had a problem that, after installing the app, it did not open the home page when clicking on the icon.
To resolve this, I added the following line to the `fetch` event handler in the service worker:

```
if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') return await cache.match(event.request) as Response;
```

Now the app opens normally. But if I go to any other page in the app and refresh, the page doesn't work. So I remove the code snippet above and the refresh works, but the problem of not opening the app returns.
I don't know if this has anything to do with the SvelteKit structure, but I have this little problem.